# Running Expo app on physical iPhone from Debian WSL2

Tags: react-native, expo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am unable to run my expo app from a debian terminal using wsl2. I scan the QR code but the app loads in expos loading screen and tells me to check my internet connection.

I tried running the app both from windows powershell and wsl (debian) but neither works. I was expecting it to work from windows powershell but I guess because i have installed all packages and stuff with debian there's some compatibility issue. I'm pretty new to wsl and how the entire thing works so..